# Use bbox to clip image in R

Tags: r, crop, intersection, bounding-box, clip

I have the bounding box of a shapefile. I want to use this bbox to clip an image which I have as both a raster and a shapefile.

I have attempted to use gIntersection and crop (see below). Not sure if I need to convert the bbox to a polygon to do this.

```
raster = county raster 
plot_parcel_bb = bbox 
county_shp = county shape

    #4.Use bounding box to clip the appropriate county imagery tile (raster&vector in QGIS)

#Check class
class(raster) 
class(plot_parcel_bb)

#Check extents
extent(raster)
extent(plot_parcel_bb)

#set the raster image extent to match the shp extent
new_raster<- setExtent(raster, ext = county_shp)
extent(new_raster)

#check the raster and plot parcels crs
st_crs(new_raster)
st_crs(plot_parcel_bb)

#make sure both crs's match 
crs(new_raster) <- "EPSG:4326"
st_crs(new_raster)


#this does not overlap
cropped<- crop(new_raster, extent(plot_parcel_bb), filename = "cropped", snap = 'near')
```

Do I need to overlay the image shapefile and raster and clip the bbox from it? Perhaps I am starting at the wrong point here. I am unsure on which step to take first.

Am I in the correct place with this site - https://datacarpentry.org/r-raster-vector-geospatial/11-vector-raster-integration/

Thank you

Comment: See `raster::crop` --- or, if you want a more elaborate answer, edit your question to more clearly explains what you are after and where you are stuck, by including a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*.

Comment: Will do, thank you Robert

Answer (score 0):

See the examples in `?raster::crop` or `?terra::crop`

Example data

```
library(raster)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
r <- raster(extent(p) + 3, resolution=0.1)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
```

Crop raster with polygon extent

```
x <- crop(r, p)
```

From what I can see you seem to a bit confused about some of the basics and it is probably a good idea to first work through a tutorial, e.g. from https://rspatial.org/

Comment: I am confused, you are correct, thank you Robert, I appreciate it (: